# rails checkbox routing error + how do i make a checkbox which is also a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a check_box_tag form, there is a checkbox and i want it to display the value from the database, that works.
If I try to update it, i recieve a routing error.

I want to have a checkbox which fetches the results the checkbox but also works as a form, how can I do that?

```
<%= check_box_tag("order", "send_mail", method: "post", action: "updateform") %>
```

controller:

```
def updateform
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    if @order.update_attributes(params[:send_mail])
       @order
    end
end
```

routing:

```
collection do
    post 'orders/updateform'
end
```

i get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/orders/613"
```

what did I wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following example, and go to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    post 'updateform'
  end
end
```

For example, this will recognize /orders/1/updateform.

Comment: alright, i changed my question, because I think that i got an understanding problem of the form. btw. still same error

Comment: "checkbox which is also a form" something smell here :P
Try just with form_tag and put inside that form check box.
Set form action to updateform.

Answer (score 0):

Try `member` instead of `collection` in your routing.  Collection is for things like index.  member is for when you have an id for a specific entry.